# Thumbrule on which collections have the Length or Count property - C#

Tags: c#, .net

Some C# collections have the count and some of them have the length property. Is there a thumbrule to find out which one has which and why the discrepency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say general ***Thumbrule*** would be the following:

- `Count` is for collections with a
  variable length, i.e. Lists (from
  `ICollection`)
- `Length` is for fixed length
  collections, i.e. Arrays, or other
  immutable objects, i.e. `string`.

**UPDATE:**

Just to elaborate `Count` comes through from `ICollection` and doesn't always indicate variability, for example (as per [Greg Beech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13552/greg-beech)'s comment) the [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) has the `Count` property but it is not variable, however it does implement `ICollection`.

Perhaps a more exact rule of thumb would be:

- `Count` indicates that something
  implements `ICollection`
- `Length` indicates immutability.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's for collections that have a variable length; `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` clearly is immutable and has a fixed length yet it has a `Count` property. It's just for anything that implements `ICollection`, irrespective of its other behaviour.

Comment: Very good points, obviously there's exceptions, but the OP wanted a thumbrule.

Answer (score 3):

If the type implements [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) it will have the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.count.aspx) property. [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) on the other hand is not standard and is defined as a property of the [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) class so all fixed size arrays will have it as well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said `Count` comes from ICollection and `Length` is specifically defined on certain types, typically types that are immutable such as `String` and `Array`.

To me, `Count` implies mutability as the count of something can easily change. `Length` *feels* more immutable. The length of a given object usually doesn't change without drastic measure.

Also keep in mind there is the extension method `Count()` defined in LINQ, which provides a common interface to both of these properties. LINQ is smart enough to return Count() as efficiently as it can (ie if the Count or Length properties exist it will invoke them), so it's a decent alternative.